# Crash when installing Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, software-installation, lubuntu, windows-10, crash

I tried to install Ubuntu with Windows alongside it. I choose this option when the install window was open.
Ubuntu isntallation started and when it almost finished it said: 
 `"software install crashed" (or something like that).` 
Then it said: 
 `"You can report the problem..."` 
 so I presssed `report`, it took a few moments and that this page opened: 
    `https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1871268` 
 
So, what should I do? 
 Did my windows installation get removed? What about my Linux install? How do I install Ubuntu again?  
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Update: 
I check for others questions like this but I didn't found.

Comment: The question is very unclear. How did you try to install Ubuntu? Please [edit] the question and describe the steps you did.

Comment: Are you sure that your installation media is valid?  Does it pass integrity checks?

Comment: What version Ubuntu? Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB. Open a `terminal`. Type `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Tell me the answer, and tell me the EXACT make/model # of your computer or motherboard. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.